# Adobe Animate CC animation export to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, export, animate-cc

We are extensively using Adobe Animate CC for creating assets and their animations(Characters, effects, props, etc) for a 2d game that we are planning to develop in Unity.

However, we are unable to export animations from  Animate CC to Unity as per our requirements.

Are there any methods or plugins that would help us with exporting animations from  Animate CC to Unity?

(Just for additional Details if it helps) - We need a character to be exported with animations to Unity from Animate CC with each body part(hands, face, etc) separate so that we can add colliders in unity which will move along with the animated body part.

Any help will be grateful,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Animate CC 2017 or later, you can create a texture atlas and import it into your game engine.

Take a look here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/create-sprite-sheet.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Whilst links to external sites are always helpful, it's best to provide some context or an excerpt as from time to time links go dead. 
Check out the answering guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FlashSpriteSheetImporter](https://github.com/prankard/FlashSpriteSheetImporter) to process the Animate's xml to slice the frames of animation out of the sprite sheet.

[See this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcgmO7sWdWk).